# batch tasks plugin setting permissions on jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugin-batch-task

We're using the batch task plugin([here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Batch+Task+Plugin)) on our jenkins server

i would like to restrict access/set permissions for certain tasks for individual users

For example:

User A can see tasks=> Push to production, Push to Dev

User B can only see task=> Push to Dev

I know I can create a separate job for the specified task however that would just take up more space (as we have many many projects) I would like to see if that level of granularity for setting tasks permissions is possible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are many (if any) Jenkins plugins which integrate that deeply with user permissions — you'd have to add a [feature request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=10172&issuetype=2).

You can also try asking on the [jenkinsci-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/jenkinsci-users) to see if anybody has similar experience with this type of issue.